# Change color text on buttons

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using a theme on wordpress that have yellow color on the button but the text is white on hover and none hover so I want the text would be black in both way.
I have tried to use this code but it make the color black only on hover, how to make it black in both ways?

```
input[type = "submit"]:hover {
color: black;
```

Comment: input[type = "submit"]{color:black}

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
input[type="submit"], 
input[type="submit"]:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: But what if the button is black and text color white and when hover it it turns to yellow and the text also turns to white? So I wanna only change the color text when I hover it.

Comment: try this way- input[type="submit"]:hover {
  color: black;
}

Comment: It doesn't work, maybe the button type are not subit?
the code looks like that for the button  `<a id="thb-button-5dfcaca2724f8" class="btn style1 medium black small-radius " href="#" target="_self" role="button">`

Comment: then try -  `.btn.style1:hover{color: black;}`

Comment: Awsome, how to even make the arrow inside the button black? `class="btn style1 small  black small-radius animation bottom-to-top   arrow-enabled"`

Comment: you can use Font Awesome icon or arrow image

Comment: there are already built an arrow in the button but that one are also white as I showed you in the code

Answer (score 0):

```css
input[type=submit], input[type=submit]:hover {
  color:black  
}
```

```html
<input type='submit'></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type = "submit"],input[type = "submit"]:hover{
color: black !important;
}
```

try this way
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this. hope will help you

```css
input[type=submit]:hover {
 background:#ccc !important; 
 color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
 <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```